# create exactly 1000 unique accounts with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have account model with this schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { 
    type: String, 
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
});

var Account = mongoose.model("Account", schema);
```

and in my `app.js` i have this code

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var account = new Account({username: random()});
}
```

but `random()` could generate duplicate value and because username is unique it will not save so how i can create exactly 1000 account?

I try some ways, like before saving accounts check existence of `random()` value on database and if exists create new one rescusivly but because mongoose is asynchronous this is not work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [Mongoose's home page](http://mongoosejs.com/) they have this example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('meow');
});
```

When you save `kitty`, you can pass in a callback which will tell you if it succeeded or not. So if it fails you can try again (presumably with a different username). In your example you could do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    createAccount();
}

function createAccount() {
    var account = new Account({username: random()});
    account.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            createAccount(); //try again
    });
}
```